# How can I access environment variables from ant on OSX?

Tags: macos, ant

The `<property environment="env"/>` call seems not to work. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: That should work - can you post an example showing which environment variable you're trying read and how?

Answer (score 0):

`<sysproperty key="variable-name-in-ant" value="${environment.variable}"/>`